# check if a sheet exists in excel

Tags: interop, excel-2007

How do i check if a sheet exists in a excel using interop. I tried  the following but it throws an COMException if not there.. Is there a better way of finding out than actually looking at the exception

```
    Worksheet sheet = null;
    Sheets worksheets = some;

    sheet = (Worksheet)worksheets.get_Item("sheetName");
    if(sheet!=null)
{
//do something
}
```

Edit:

Thanks for the input guys.

i wrote a function

```
private Dictionary<string, Worksheet> GetSheetsMap(Sheets worksheets)
{

    if (worksheets == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("worksheets");


    Dictionary<string, Worksheet> map = new Dictionary<string, Worksheet>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    foreach (Worksheet s in worksheets)
    {
        map.Add(s.Name, s);
    }

    return map;
}
```

And i use it as below

```
 Dictionary<string, Worksheet> sheetMap = GetSheetsMap(worksheets);
            Worksheet sheet = null;


            if (sheetMap.TryGetValue(ExtendedTemplateManager.BasicUserTemplate, out sheet))
            {
                //found it.
            }
else
{
// not
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have a Workbook object? If so, you can iterate over the Workbook.Sheets array and check the Name property of each Sheet.

```
foreach (Sheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
{
    if (sheet.Name.equals("sheetName"))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First consider if an exception isn't actually appropriate.  You expect a sheet with a certain name to be there.  If it isn't, can you still meaningful continue running your program?

If you can, you can avoid the exception by iterating the sheets collection and look for a match on the Name property.

Comment: i have to implement logic based on whether a sheet is present or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LINQ way to do it (and this method returns null if the sheet doesn't exist):

```
workbook.Worksheets.Cast<Worksheet>().FirstOrDefault(worksheet => worksheet.Name == worksheetName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have worksheet and workbook objects them you can do parent check

if (sheet.Parent == workbook)